# How to find a library source path? $(call ???, shared_library) - Android NDK build

Tags: android, android-ndk, gnu-make

I am looking for a way to find a shared library source files path in an Android.mk.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE                := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := test.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES      := libssl
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES      := libcrypto_static
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(warning libssl source files are located at... $(call WHAT???, openssl))
```

I'm sure there a `$(call something)` that find openssl source files path.

If $(call import-module) can find it, then we should be able to find it.

> $(call import-module, name)
>   And this will look for the module
>   tagged name in the list of directories referenced by your
>   NDK_MODULE_PATH environment variable, and include its Android.mk
>   automatically for you.

I guess it's __ndk_modules.openssl.PATH but I can't access this NDK variable from Android.mk. See [Android NDK definitions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/core/definitions.mk).

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.

```
include openssl.Android.mk # defines LOCAL_MODULE = libssl and includes $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE                := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := test.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES      := libssl
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES      := libcrypto_static
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(warning libssl source files are located at... $(__ndk_modules.libssl.PATH))
```

Your mistake was that the name of the module is same as the one you provide in `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.

Note that NDK provides a strong debugging tool for such situations, you can `$(call modules_dump_database)` to see what you've actually collected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get a ``openssl.Android.mk: No file or folder of that type`` when running ``mka module-name`` or ``mmm external/module-folder``. By the way, modules_dump_database returns nothing, maybe there's a need to initialize NDK_DEBUG_MODULES somehow.

Comment: Well, this is not an `ndk-build`, but platform build. The rules there are slightly different.

Comment: OK, I guess there's no way to find it except by modifying the platform-build source code. I see that most modules use `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = external/some-module/some-include-folder`. I don't find that very proper but that's the way to go when importing system libraries that don't use `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES`.